# python, adding and overwriting a value in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a list called foo with n random values stored in it. I want to be able to make a loop that continuously adds random values and stores the new value in foo[i] this is my code so far. Anytime I run this I am unable to exit the while loop.

```
import random
foo=[]
i=0
flag = False

print("How many horses do you want to race?")
horses = eval(input())
print (horses)

while flag == False:
    for i in range(horses):
        foo.insert(i, random.randrange(4,41))
    print(a)
    if foo[i] >= 5280:
        flag = True
    else:
        i=i+1
```

I think the reason this is not working is because I'm not actually adding to the value stored in foo[i] in the line

```
        foo.insert(i, random.randrange(4,41))
```

but I am unable to figure out what to do instead. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `eval(input())`: avoid. do `int(input()) instead`

Comment: problem is you're using your `i` index outside your loop. That's really strange...

Comment: You want to insert  how many itens in foo ? In this code you will insert n times the elements!
Probably the line: if foo[i] >= 5280: 
Is: if  i >= 5280:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to change it to:

```
import random

i=0
flag = False

print("How many horses do you want to race?")
horses = int(input())
print (horses)

foo = [0] * horses #initialize horse values
while not flag:
    for i in range(horses):
        foo[i] += random.randrange(4,41) #move the horse a random amount
        if foo[i] >= 5280:
            flag = True #a horse has won
            break #exit the loop
```

I:

- deleted the `a` variable that you were not initializing
- took out using the `i` variable outside the loop (which you shouldn't do)
- fixed the line to actually add to the horse
- initialized all of the horses at 0
- put the line with the loop exit inside the loop so it exits during the loop
- took out `flag == False` and replaced it with `not flag:`

  - From PEP 8: `Don't compare boolean values to True or False using == .`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a question about what you wrote. What does the line foo=[0 for i in range(horses)] do? I understand that it makes a list called foo but the, 0 for i, but is messing me up. Does it start the count of the horses variable at zero? So instead if typing 3 horses the list has the indexes 0,1,2 not 0,1,2,3 like in my original code?

Comment: @DrJenkins: `[0 for i in range(horses)]` generates a list that contain as many zeros as the integer `horses` says. The value of `i` is not used; `range(n)` generates a list of 0,1,... n-1. A more idiomatic way to generate a list of `n` zeros is `[0] * n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid explicit loops over `foo` altogether.

```
foo = [0 for _ in range(horses)]  # or even [0] * horses
over_the_line = []  # Index(es) of horses that have crossed the line.
while not over_the_line:
  foo = [pos + random.randint(...) for pos in foo]  # Move them all.
  over_the_line = [i for (i, pos) in enumerate(foo) if pos >= 5280]

# Now you can decide who from over_the_line is the winner.
```

Also, if you called your variable `horse_pos` instead of `foo`, things would be easier to understand. And I hope you'll add an animation display step after each horse position update! :)